# Insert a time + n in mySQL using Zend_db_table!

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

$data = array (
                  'next' => "NOW() + 5",
                  'interval' => $dom["USER"][0]["STATUSES_COUNT"][0]["data"],
                  'good' => $good,
                  'tries' => $p->tries + 1
                );
                $where = $service->getAdapter()->quoteInto('id = ?', $p->id);
                $service->update($data, $where);

to insert something to a database using PHP on zend and mySQL.
The "next" => "NOW()" wont work. I could put the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as default value, but what i actually want is to insert the timestamp refering this moment, plus some time.

I could rewrite some parts of the program to use pure php dates(instade of pure mySQL dates). Dont know what is best, or what should i do. Do you know how i could make this update work with mySQL doing the timing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it with the next statement, very usefull:

```
'next' => new Zend_Db_Expr('TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE,1,NOW())'),
```